# Make jquery increment a text box number and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to be able to click the button and have it copy this:

```
<tr id="1">
<td>
    <input type="number" class="cue">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="time">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text">
</td>
</tr>
```

And be able to change the id of the `<tr>` based on what is before it.  I also want it to change the value of the number box based on the variable cueset.

When you press the button to add a row it calls `add_row()`

```
function add_row(rowCount)
   {
    for(i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
    {
        index = index + 1;
        $('table').append( $('#1').prop('id', index));
    }
   }
```

What im not sure how to do is have it change the id, or the value of the number box.

Comment: @Ronny    
     `<button id="add_row">
 Add Row
    </button>`

`$('button#add_row').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     add_row(2);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the use of rowCount and the for loop from your explanation, so here it is without them

```
function add_row()
{               
    var mostRecentTr = [].pop.call($("tr"));                
    var newNum = 1+$(mostRecentTr).attr("id");      
    var newTr = $(mostRecentTr).clone().attr("id", newNum);             
    newTr.find(".cue").val(newNum);                 
    $("table").append(newTr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastRow = jQuery('tr[id]').last();
var currCount = parseInt(lastRow.id);
var newRow = lastRow.clone()
newRow.id = currCount++;
lastRow.parent().append(newRow);
```

Though I'd suggest something a bit better like this:

```
var lastRow = jQuery('tr[counter]').last();
var currCount = parseInt(lastRow.attr('counter'));
var newRow = lastRow.clone()
newRow.attr('counter', currCount + 1).id = ('myRow' + currCount + 1);
lastRow.parent().append(newRow);
```